# Perl Win32::Console can't locate loadable

Tags: perl, console

After Win32::Console installation, sample.pl fails with:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Win32::Console
```

Cheers kes

Answer (score 2):

99 times out of 100, Win32::Console wasn't installed properly. Reinstall it.